# Canvas and Video - HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, html5-video

I see that you cannot stretch a video to fit a window size. It keeps the aspect ration.

I can play a video through canvas, cant you do it with canvas? Where canvas stretches to fit the window?

It seems logical that It would work

Comment: If you stretch it and lose the aspect ratio it will look warped, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes it would, thats besides the point. We have signage solutions and thats what the client wants. Give the people what they want..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very easily with drawImage's optional arguments specifying width and height. For example:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var myVideo = document.createElement('video');
// Video tags usually have more than one source. Not all browsers can play Ogg/Theora
myVideo.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Mockingbird_Spring.ogv";
myVideo.autoplay = true;
myVideo.loop = true;


setInterval(function () {
    // video is 1280 x 720 but I am stretching it to 400x20
    ctx.drawImage(myVideo, 0, 0, 400, 20);
    // Also draw it normally
    ctx.drawImage(myVideo, 0, 100, 128, 72);
}, 10)
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/zwwyd/

Comment: Also consider requestAnimationFrame with this approach

Comment: I agree that requestAnimationFrame should be used in production, but how (or even if) you animate it is up to the asker, setTimeout is just the laziest way to prove that it works (no need to stuff in a shim)

Comment: Yep that's true enough, just thought Id add it as your answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the video.js API instead though, your choice :)

[Link to video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) (it's open source of course)

Comment: Does this api have this exact functionality? To make it fit the screen and not keep the aspect ration?

Comment: There is a video using that API in the website I've shared you may test it and see